# DateTime.ToString("ddd, MMM dd", new CultureInfo("en-CA")) - returning two diff values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core

Local Machine:
DateTime.ToString("ddd, MMM dd", new CultureInfo("en-CA")) -> Get it by Tue, Oct 26
Server(PCF) :
DateTime.ToString("ddd, MMM dd", new CultureInfo("en-CA")) -> Get it by **Thu.**, **Oct.** 26

I would like to show the above date format in UI, actual date we are getting from service is 10/26/2021.
First we are converting to Datetime using DateTime.Parse Method with CultureInvariant, then same date we are passing to format as above.

Above format is behaving differently, Linux servers are giving weekname, month name with period, where as in windows its giving wihtout period.
How to avoid period when we run over linux machines ?

Comment: `DateTime` is presumably a property of something - or you haven't given us the actual code. So where is that value coming from? Please provide more information.

Comment: Date is coming as string "10/19/2021" , formatting as DateTime.Parse(stringDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)  Note: Reason for InvariantCulture date we are receiving from service as mm/dd/yyyy, so when we try to format culture specific its failing, so first converting from InvariantCulture and then getting the format as per country specific.

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't really explain much - in particular, *neither* of the dates in the question matches "10/19/2021". Please read https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and edit your question to provide a *lot* more information.

Comment: our code is deployed to PCF environments (linux machines). Is that causing the issue ? while when I run the application from windows I see the format is good.

Comment: So just to check, you don't actually care that the values you've shown are for different dates? You only care about the format? Your question is *really* unclear at the moment.

Comment: Sorry Jon, Now I updated the question. I am looking why date format working differently with windows and linux machines. to avoid period any thing need to take care ?

Comment: It's easy to get lost in this question since it still contains superfluous information and red herrings. For instance, I was wondering how the single datetime value could produce Tuesday on one machine and Thursday on another. You should 1) make a [mcve] so that it's clear what value you are using and then 2) only use `"ddd"` as the format string and then 3) explain that you're wondering where the full stop is coming from/missing. My guess is that there is a difference in `new CultureInfo("en-CA").DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedDayNames`. On my machine, running in .NET 5, there are full stops.

Comment: Are the two machines running the same application and/or the same .NET version?

Answer (score 0):

Check if the time on the server is correct. This happened to me once while working on apache server.

Comment: Great response, and good job including your own experience! You can make your answers even stronger by linking supporting documentation (such as help pages on how to do this, or related Stack Overflow questions).

Comment: our code is deployed to PCF environments (linux machines). Is that causing the issue ? while when I run the application from windows I see the format is good.